# Audio hacked. System may be compromised?

Tags: windows-7, audio, virus, speakers

My speakers are making a sound like someone talking from other computer. Like the sound that online game players do. It's only noise, strange microphone noise. Have I been hacked? I checked all proccesses and I can't see anything out of common.

I haven't installed anything recently, and it suddenly started.
Disconnected from the internet and it's still happening. Now I'm closing every program or process I see and checking when it stops. It still hasn't stopped.

Update 1:

Everything solved. Thanks everyone for your help. Restarted and solved.

Update 2:

Ok, Not solved. Now, 45 minutes after restarting the computer the sound suddenly started again. I will try with headphones and post news. Thanks in advance.

Update 3:

Still happening with headphones. Really disturbing.

Update 4:

15 hours without noise. Everything seems fine. Must have been some kind of 
interference, but still don't know what could have caused it. 
Thanks everyone, I was unquiet.

Comment: Probably not. Some wireless headsets or walkie talkies nearby could be being picked up by your speaker wiring...

Comment: It doesn't sound like a virus or hacking.  Various sources can sometimes get picked up by the audio, even from something acting like an antenna.  Often it's a grounding or shielding problem.

Comment: If that's the problem (it seems plausible) how can i solve it? It's really annoying.

I haven't changed anything from my hardware.

Comment: Replace speakers with headphones and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Everything solved. Thanks everyone for your help. Restarted and solved.

Comment: Ok, Not solved. Now, 45 minutes after restarting the computer the sound suddenly started again. I will try with headphones and post news. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have a microphone plugged in, try plugging one in.  If you don't have a microphone, plug an earphone or headphones into the mic jack just to test.

Comment: sounds like interference to me.  At home, we had a sound system that picked up the radios of passing trucks and such.  We'd be watching a movie and all of a sudden we're hearing a random conversation.

Comment: I have a built-in microphone, disconnected and connected and nothing happened, but when i did the test, the noise had stopped an hour before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you solved your issue, but here is how I track down stray interference in an audio system.

1. Wiggle your cords and check your connections - if a stray wire is connecting your mic to your speakers you can often hear faint voices coming from the speakers.  Loose connections can cause all kinds of havoc as well, so address them first.
2. Put a cordless phone near the wires and make a call - if you hear clicking, buzzing or fuzz in the speakers during this test you need better shielding or grounding.  900mhz phone systems work best, but you may be able to get away with using a cell phone to make a standard (not VOIP) call.  Microwaves are also excellent sources of interference - their hum is very distinctive to my ears.
3. Try a tinfoil wrap with a grounding wire. Solder or clamp a wire to some tinfoil, ground the wire to the same ground as your audio gear (your computer case if this is a normal desktop computer) and wrap the tinfoil around your speaker/signal wires.  If the background noise decreases, you know that wire is picking up stray signals.  Replace it with a quality, shielded cable (ideal), add a ferrite core (sometimes called a "doughnut") to the wire (not-bad) or improvise a shield from tinfoil and heatshrink (hackish/desert island worthy).
4. If shielding does not help, crosstalk or poor grounding are leading to this issue... these are harder to handle.  For crosstalk replacing the cable with a twisted pair cable will help.  Poor grounding is an audio techs nightmare, but essentially you will want to listen to the ground at different points, find a nice clean ground then reconnect everything to it.

Some links that cover the ideas above in more depth:

- https://www.audio-technica.com/cms/site/d0c406516fd8b42b/
- [Mystery radio station playing through headphones. How to find all sources of sound?](https://superuser.com/questions/859759/mystery-radio-station-playing-through-headphones-how-to-find-all-sources-of-sou)
- From: http://www.empiricalaudio.com/computer-audio/technical-papers/myths-and-snake-oil

> **Ferrites on Speaker Cables**
>
> What happens when Ferrites are installed on
> speaker cables? This is a more interesting question. Ferrites, with
> the right composition and size can be helpful for optimizing a
> speaker/cable/amplifier combination. I would avoid using the large
> clamp-on Ferrites used for EMI (Electro-Magnetic-Interference), since
> these generally add too much inductance. The Image Clarifier offered
> by Empirical Audio is a device that works for audio because the
> composition and size of the Ferrites is specifically chosen for audio
> cables. The Ferrite cores should be installed on one wire, not across
> both wires. The reason that Ferrites can improve the performance of
> speaker cables lies in their ability to add inductance and loss to the
> cable. We believe that this inductance reduces the natural resonances
> in a cable, which we believe can become audible through secondary
> effects. The ferrite creates a low-pass filter at very high frequency.